# OBIEE - Showing the Display Value from a Double Column / Presentation Variable

Tags: oracle, obiee

I have a double column laid out as so:
**Display Value   Code Column**
Apr-17               201704
May-17              201705
Jun-17               201706

A 'between values' prompt is setup to show the Display Value and Filter by Column Code, and it's been given a presentation value.

So say I selected Apr-17 to Jun-17, the presentation value displays **Apr-17,Jun-17** in the narrative, however I'd prefer it read like **Apr-17 to Jun-17**

I'm unable to use the SUBSTRING function in the narrative, so I decided to add the presentation value into a column and work from there.

However, once I add the presentation value the Column Formula, it displays the Code Column values instead of the Display Values, so:

**201704,201706** instead of **Apr-17,Jun-17**

Is there a fix for this, or an alternative way of getting the desired formatting?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your filtering seems extremely standard so I question your use of presentation variables in the first place.

If you just use out-of-the-box filter functionality with columns then you can just use the filters view.